# Why do view port extent and window extent of a DC keep constant even if I resize the window?

Tags: winapi, gdi

Here is my WindowProc function's code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
            {
                RECT rect;
                rect.left = 0;
                rect.right = LOWORD(lParam);
                rect.top = 0;
                rect.bottom = HIWORD(lParam);
                InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rect, true);
            }
        case WM_PAINT:
            {
                int height = 50;
                TCHAR buff[256] = { 0 };
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                SetMapMode(hdc, MM_TEXT);
                SIZE size1;
                GetWindowExtEx(hdc, &size1);
                SIZE size2;
                GetViewportExtEx(hdc, &size2);
                _stprintf_s(buff, TEXT("TEXT MODE:WindowExtent=[%d, %d], ViewportExtent=[%d,%d]"),size1.cx,size1.cy, size2.cx,size2.cy);
                TextOut(hdc,0, height * 0,buff, _tcslen(buff));
                
                
                SetMapMode(hdc, MM_HIENGLISH);
                GetWindowExtEx(hdc, &size1);
                GetViewportExtEx(hdc, &size2);
                memset(buff, 0, 256);
                _stprintf_s(buff, TEXT("HIENGLISH MODE:WindowExtent=[%d, %d], ViewportExtent=[%d,%d]"), size1.cx, size1.cy, size2.cx, size2.cy);
                TextOut(hdc, 0, -height * 1, buff, _tcslen(buff));
                
                
                SetMapMode(hdc, MM_LOENGLISH);
                GetWindowExtEx(hdc, &size1);
                GetViewportExtEx(hdc, &size2);
                memset(buff, 0, 256);
                _stprintf_s(buff, TEXT("LOENGLISH MODE:WindowExtent=[%d, %d], ViewportExtent=[%d,%d]"), size1.cx, size1.cy, size2.cx, size2.cy);
                TextOut(hdc, 0, -height * 2, buff, _tcslen(buff));
                
                
                SetMapMode(hdc, MM_HIMETRIC);
                GetWindowExtEx(hdc, &size1);
                GetViewportExtEx(hdc, &size2);
                memset(buff, 0, 256);
                _stprintf_s(buff, TEXT("HIMETRIC MODE:WindowExtent=[%d, %d], ViewportExtent=[%d,%d]"), size1.cx, size1.cy, size2.cx, size2.cy);
                TextOut(hdc, 0, -height * 3, buff, _tcslen(buff));

                SetMapMode(hdc, MM_LOMETRIC);
                GetWindowExtEx(hdc, &size1);
                GetViewportExtEx(hdc, &size2);
                memset(buff, 0, 256);
                _stprintf_s(buff, TEXT("LOMETRIC MODE:WindowExtent=[%d, %d], ViewportExtent=[%d,%d]"), size1.cx, size1.cy, size2.cx, size2.cy);
                TextOut(hdc, 0,  -height * 4, buff, _tcslen(buff));

                SetMapMode(hdc, MM_TWIPS);
                GetWindowExtEx(hdc, &size1);
                GetViewportExtEx(hdc, &size2);
                memset(buff, 0, 256);
                _stprintf_s(buff, TEXT("TWIPS MODE:WindowExtent=[%d, %d], ViewportExtent=[%d,%d]"), size1.cx, size1.cy, size2.cx, size2.cy);
                TextOut(hdc, 0, -height * 5, buff, _tcslen(buff));

                SetMapMode(hdc, MM_ISOTROPIC);
                GetWindowExtEx(hdc, &size1);
                GetViewportExtEx(hdc, &size2);
                memset(buff, 0, 256);
                _stprintf_s(buff, TEXT("ISOTROPIC MODE:WindowExtent=[%d, %d], ViewportExtent=[%d,%d]"), size1.cx, size1.cy, size2.cx, size2.cy);
                TextOut(hdc, 0,  -height * 6, buff, _tcslen(buff));

                SetMapMode(hdc, MM_ANISOTROPIC);
                GetWindowExtEx(hdc, &size1);
                GetViewportExtEx(hdc, &size2);
                memset(buff, 0, 256);
                _stprintf_s(buff, TEXT("ANISOTROPIC MODE:WindowExtent=[%d, %d], ViewportExtent=[%d,%d]"), size1.cx, size1.cy, size2.cx, size2.cy);
                TextOut(hdc, 0,  -height * 7, buff, _tcslen(buff));
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                break;
            }
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

It is not complex that I just want to print window extent and view port extent under different mapping mode in the window. But I find that the printed values do not change at all even though I resize the window by dragging the edges of it. Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extents do not change with the window size. For some mapping modes, they depend on the (pixel, or assumed physical) size of the screen, but for example `MM_TEXT` always has [viewport and window extents of 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/predefined-mapping-modes).

If what you're actually looking for the height and width of your window (client area), but in logical coordinates, you could try something like this:

```
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
SetMapMode(hdc, MM_HIENGLISH);
DPtoLP(hdc, (PPOINT)&rect, 2);
SetMapMode(hdc, MM_TEXT);
```

[GetClientRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclientrect) gets the height and width of the window, in device units.
[DPtoLP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-dptolp) converts those to logical units, in this case `MM_HIENGLISH` units (thousandths of an inch);
the window width is now in `rect.right` and the height in logical units is in `rect.bottom`.

I've added a `SetMapMode` back to `MM_TEXT`; you may want to do the same before calling `TextOut`, or whatever map mode you prefer for that.

Answer (score 1):

The viewport extents and window extents are not used for most of the [page-to-device mapping modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/mapping-modes-and-translations) (specifically MM_HIENGLISH, MM_LOENGLISH, MM_HIMETRIC, MM_LOMETRIC, MM_TEXT, and MM_TWIPS).

For MM_ISOTROPIC and MM_ANISOTROPIC, it's the *ratios* of the extents that are used to determine the scaling factors.  Therefore, their absolute values don't matter and there's no need for them to change when the window is resized.